# C# MVC - How to display an uneditable checkbox with an id so I can grab it with Jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've come across an issue with a field bound to a bool.

I want to show a checkbox representing a bool field in my model. I don't want the user to be able to edit it. But I need to be able to edit it's checked state using jquery - and for this it needs to have an id.

I can't seem to do it. Here's what I have tried:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Deleted, null)
```

This shows the correct checked state but there's no id on the checkbox.

I noticed that using EditorFor you can apply HTML Attributes in the below fashion, but it doesn't work in DisplayFor - they are ignored.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Deleted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "cbCourtDeleted" } })
```

So I then thought I could use and EditorFor and apply `readonly` and `disabled` attributes (i've done this with textboxfor before and it works well:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Deleted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", @disabled = "disabled", @id = "cbCourtDeleted" } })
```

but when used in Editor for (for checkboxes at least) the checked state isn't displayed - it appears unchecked, but it does have the required id.

Question: How can I display a bool field from my model that has an id so I can get access to it via jquery/javascript?

Comment: Its a bit unclear what your trying to do and why. `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not display a checkbox. You need `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Deleted, new { disabled  = "disabled" })` which will add the `id="Deleted"` attribute. And if the value of property `Deleted` is `true` it will be checked. But disabled controls do not post back a value so even if its checked, your property will be `false` when you submit.

Comment: Hi @stephenmuecke, @Html.DisplayFor() does display a checkbox when linked to a bool in the Model. The scenario, in a single page I have the Details View - then upon clicking edit, I have a Modal that opens with the edit view - (only 2 editable fields). When the user clicks save, I just JQuery to grab the data in these 2 fields and make an ajax call to save - a success/failure message is returned. Upon success I close the modal and update the Details UI fields with the new values.

Comment: It does **not** display a checkbox unless you have created a custom `DisplayTemplate`! - it displays the text `"True"` or `"False"` (perhaps you mean `EditorFor()`?) And what does the checkbox have to do with your last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Deleted, new { @id = "chkDeleted", @disabled = "true"})
```

Comment: perfect - I thought I'd tried that one during my many attempts - obviously not!! I hate these simple things that take longer than they should!!

Answer (score 1):

The HTML input element will have `id` and `name` attributes set to the property name of the model class, setting the id with an attribute is probably not needed,

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Deleted)
```

When the checkbox will not allow editing, and if the `disabled` attribute is used to prevent editing, it might help to add another property to the model for returning the value back to the server, since the browser does not return values of disabled inputs. This new property can be a hidden field and can be set with JQuery.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Deleted, new { disabled = "disabled" })
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeletedAndBackToServer)
```

Comment: I believe if the hiddenfor uses M.Deleted, it will bind to the property.

Comment: agreed, the second property is not needed and m.Deleted can be used in the hidden field.